# Cant able to understand the below query ,any one explain?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select table_name, 
to_number(
  extractvalue(
    xmltype(
      dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
       'select count(*) c from '||table_name
    ))
  ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')
) count
from user_tables
order by table_name;
```

I know it is giving the total count of row of each table . But what to know how it working ?

Answer (score 5):

Examining the query starting from innermost part is best way to understand:

```
'select count(*) c from ' || table_name
```

creates a string containing query selecting the number of records from the table referred to by `table_name`, so if `table_name` contains *xyz* the query will be `select count(*) from xyz`.

```
xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(<query>))
```

executes the dynamically generated query, producing an XML result.

```
to_number(extractvalue(<xml>, '/ROWSET/ROW/C'))
```

fetches a specific value from the XML generated before, following a specific path. We need to assume the XML looks like`<ROWSET><ROW><C>value</C></ROW></ROWSET>`. The extracted value, yet a string, is then converted to a number.

```
select table_name, <number> count from user_tables order by table_name
```

is what finally remains...

Answer (score 4):

Break it down:

- `'select count(*) c from '||table_name` gives you a string containing a query against a specific table (from `user_tables`);
- `dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name)` uses [the dbms_xmlgen package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html) to run that dynamic query string and returns the result as an XML document, but as a CLOB;
- `xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))` converts that CLOB to actual XML;
- `extractvalue(..., '/ROWSET/ROW/C')` extracts the `C` node value from that XML (there is only one per document, and there is one document per table), as a string;
- `to_number(...)` just converts that string to a number.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3cf565e0746bd9e93e9478e580f71751) with three dummy tables, showing the intermediate steps.

However, the version you have seems to have originated [with Laurent Schneider in 2007](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html), and things have moved on a bit since then. The `extractvalue()` function is deprecated so you should [use XMLQuery instead](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392), and you can skip a step by using [`getxmltype()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html#GUID-8128DE5B-14CF-4D47-905B-733A49045772) instead of `xmltype(getxml())`:

```
select table_name,
  to_number(
    xmlquery(
      '/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
      passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select count(*) c from '||table_name)
      returning content
    )
  ) count
from user_tables
order by table_name;
```

Or (as @Padders mentioned) you could use XMLTable, with a CTE or inline view to provide the XML; which perhaps makes this example a bit more obscure, but is useful if you have more than one value to extract:

```
select t.table_name, x.count
from (
  select table_name,
    dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select count(*) c from '||table_name) as xml
  from user_tables
) t
cross apply xmltable (
  '/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing t.xml
  columns count number path 'C'
) x
order by table_name;
```

The principal is the same though, and I've included those versions in [an expanded db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d91908e60c6431fda569cb20bb01b57c).

(Incidentally, I'm not advocating using a keyword like `count` as a column alias - it's better to avoid those; I'm just sticking with the alais from your original query.)

Comment: Possibly worth noting that XMLTABLE would be another option here and could be useful for dynamic SQLs returning more than one column.